# How to get a standalone Windows 7 installation to synchronise time (NTP)

Tags: windows-7, time, ntp

I am trying to get my Windows 7 Professional machine to synchronise time correctly. This laptop is not a member of any [Windows domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain).

If I try to go to the clock settings, *Internet Time* tab, and click on "Update Now", it tells me that an error occurred. Misc. commands / output from my system is below.

What else can I try?

```
w32tm /monitor /domain:time.windows.com
```

> GetDcList failed with error code:  0x8007054B. 
>     Exiting with error 0x8007054B

---

> w32tm /query /configuration                      
>                                                    
>   [Configuration]                                  
>                                                    
>   EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)                         
>   AnnounceFlags: 10 (Local)                        
>   TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)               
>   MinPollInterval: 10 (Local)                      
>   MaxPollInterval: 15 (Local)                      
>   MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)             
>   MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 54000 (Local)             
>   MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 1 (Local)                 
>                                                    
>   FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)                  
>   PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)                      
>   LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)               
>   SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)                    
>   LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)                 
>   HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)                            
>   PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)                      
>   UpdateInterval: 360000 (Local)                   
>                                                    
>                                                    
>   [TimeProviders]                                  
>                                                    
>   NtpClient (Local)                                
>   DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.DLL (Local) 
>   Enabled: 1 (Local)                               
>   InputProvider: 1 (Local)                         
>   CrossSiteSyncFlags: 2 (Policy)                   
>   AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)      
>   ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Policy)           
>   ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Policy)           
>   CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)           
>   EventLogFlags: 0 (Policy)                        
>   LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)                       
>   SpecialPollInterval: 3600 (Policy)               
>   Type: NT5DS (Policy)                             
>                                                             
>   VMICTimeProvider (Local)                                  
>   DllName: C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll (Local) 
>   Enabled: 1 (Local)                                        
>   InputProvider: 1 (Local)                                  
>   NtpServer (Local)                                         
>   DllName: C:\Windows\system32\w32time.DLL (Local)          
>   Enabled: 0 (Local)                                        
>   InputProvider: 0 (Local)

---

```
w32tm /query /source
```

> Local CMOS Clock

---

```
w32tm /monitor /domain:time.windows.com
```

> GetDcList failed with error code:  0x8007054B. 
>   Exiting with error 0x8007054B

---

```
w32tm /monitor /computers:time.nist.gov
```

> time.nist.gov[192.43.244.18:123]:                        
>       ICMP: 439ms delay                                    
>       NTP: +11.0631836s offset from local clock            
>           RefID: 'ACTS' [0x53544341]                       
>           Stratum: 1                                       
>                                                            
>   Warning:                                                 
>   Reverse name resolution is best effort. It may not be    
>   correct since RefID field in time packets differs across 
>   NTP implementations and may not be using IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mine works fine. The only real differences I could spot if I ran `w32tm /query /configuration` was that I don't get anything with (policy), and rather than type nt5ds, I get ntp.

Sorry, I don't know much about how to fix it, but hopefully that may be a starting point.

Comment: Wow, just wow... That is exactly the information that I needed.  I've been looking for an answer for so long, I had given up.  Thanks so much.

Just to be clear as to how I resolved this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490845.aspx
Default options
 - NTP. Used on computers that are not joined to a domain.
 - NT5DS. Used on computers that are joined to a domain.

For some reason, mine was set to NT5D5, not NTP.  I changed it in gpedit.msc > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Windows Time Service > Time Providers > Configure Windows NTP Client.